# How to fold control statements with preprocessors in them?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, preprocessor, folding

Recently I've been working on some legacy code of some coworkers, using visual studio code I've been able to convert it so sane and readable C formatting. However, I'd like to fold some control statements as the ones written by my coworkers are at times larger than 100 lines.

In these lines I've added preprocessor control statements to enable and disable my changes.

In visual studio code I'm able to fold the code nicely, but it stops once it hits a preprocessor statement, at least the #ifdef and #ifndef.
As there is about 1 every 10 lines to fold one control statement I need to fold 10 times, kind of beats the idea behind it right?

I've tried looking for fold and collapse within the settings and some googling, but I can't find anything that might resolve my issues.

For example I have this snippet

```
if(true)
{
    Some functions();
#ifdef DEBUG
    Functions with debugging only();
#else
    Functions without debugging only();
#endif
    Some other functions();
}
```

I expect, whenever I fold if(true) that everything within this control statement is folded. This is what I'm used to and what will happen in vs2017 in Eclipse. This doesn't happen in VSCODE! Instead only Some functions(); is folded.

How can I get the VSCODE folding behavior to be similar to other IDE's?

Comment: What if you indent the preprocessor lines? Is this syntax-level folding or indentation-level folding?

Comment: O wow, I never thought of it. It appears that it is indentation-level folding. Indenting the preprocessor statements does work. In that case, is it possible to leave the preprocessor as is and still get the desired result? I'm used to preprocessors being unindented at all times, but if that's not possible I'm willing to accept it for now.

Comment: I made an answer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your editor is using indentation-level folding.

According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding:

> Folding ranges are by default evaluated based on the indentation of
>   lines. A folding range starts when a line has a smaller indent than
>   one or more following lines, and ends when there is a line with the
>   same or smaller indent.
>
> Since the 1.22 release, folding ranges can also be computed based on
>   syntax tokens of the editor's configured language. The following
>   languages already provide syntax aware folding:
>
> - Markdown, HTML, CSS, LESS, SCSS and JSON

It's possible that there are plugins to support syntax folding for other languages. If not, as a workaround you can indent the preprocessor lines.

Comment: Changing the indentation is not really an option as I use clang as a formatter which does not allow for this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286985/eclipse-how-can-i-indent-c-preprocessor-macros

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by C/C++ extension `ms-vscode.cpptools`.

You can force folding mark in options:

```js
    "editor.showFoldingControls": "always"
```

But unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an option to fold and mask inactive code when opening source file like on Eclipse or [on visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053067/how-to-collapse-all-blocks-of-ifdefs-that-will-not-be-compiled-in-visual-studio).